# How to make a single endpoint operation public in API Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-security

In API Platform, I have all the endpoints secured with JWT but I would like to have the POST User public so users can register themselves.

How can I do this at entity level?

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        "post" => ["security" => "is_granted('PUBLIC_ACCESS')"], //this does not work
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get'
    ],
)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
```

if I implement this in `security.yaml` as usual in Symfony it works

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
        - { path: ^/authentication_token, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/users, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS, methods: POST }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I just would like to know if I can do it at entity level with annotations.

Comment: yes, the API sits at root level. as mentioned with this config it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Api-Platform security rules are processed **after** Symfony's Security access rules.

So if Symfony's access rules are **stricter** than Api-Platform's rules, those apply and the request will be denied.

If if were the other way around (`security.access_rules` declared the endpoint "open", but on your resource configuration you declared a more stringent `is_granted()` configuration), it would work, since then request would go past the Symfony firewall and reach the Api-Platform access listener.

For you to be able to configure security with attributes/annotations, then the security configuration needs to be more restrictive than the one on the Symfony firewall.

E.g. set `/` to `PUBLIC_ACCESS`, and then configure `security` with the corresponding `is_granted()` on each resource.